# Ruby On Rails: Ask for Confirmation When Table Entry Associated With Another Is Destroyed

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, self-join, confirmation, ondestroy

I would like some assistance with the following problem:

I have a table of groups that is self-associated with itself, so each group is (optionally) linked to another in a hierarchical fashion. I want to write some code that will somehow check before the destruction of a group entry, if it has any children, and ask the user for confirmation, or whether they wish to delete the child groups as well.

I've looked at callbacks, but I don't know how to get the confirmation request to the end user in the view, and then get the response back to the model's callback.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

(Note: I'm a Rails noob)

Maybe you could probably use, say, a "before_destroy" wrapper in your models somehow:

```
def before_destroy
    raise flag unless okay_to_destroy?
end
```

But since this decision is pushed to the user before you even destroy any models, it seems to make the most sense to me to just handle this straight forwardly. Present the user with the relevant information (# children, confirmation of parent to delete), let them select a radio button or whatever to destroy children/just parent/cancel, then destroy the appropriate records.